# Purpose of DebugPlugin.exec()

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am trying to understand what exactly the `DebugPlugin.exec(String[] cmdLine, File workingDirectory)` method does.

I first encountered this method in the article [How to write an Eclipse debugger](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Debugger/how-to.html).

**Plug-in: core, Package: pda.launching, Class: PDALaunchDelegate, Method: launch**

```
commandList.add(file.getLocation().toOSString()); 
int requestPort = -1;
int eventPort = -1;
if (mode.equals(ILaunchManager.DEBUG_MODE)) {
    requestPort = findFreePort();
    eventPort = findFreePort();
    if (requestPort == -1 || eventPort == -1) {
        abort("Unable to find free port", null);
    }
    commandList.add("-debug");
    commandList.add("" + requestPort );
    commandList.add("" + eventPort );
} 
String[] commandLine = (String[]) 
commandList.toArray(new String[commandList.size()]);
Process process = DebugPlugin.exec(commandLine, null);
IProcess p = DebugPlugin.newProcess(launch, process, path);
if (mode.equals(ILaunchManager.DEBUG_MODE)) {
    IDebugTarget target = new PDADebugTarget(launch,p,requestPort,eventPort );
    launch.addDebugTarget(target);
}
```

Now, I have seen the method again going through the `AntLaunchDelegate` class in an Ant Plugin. What I don't get is `commandline`. Is it set of instructions that are executed? I have already looked into the `DebugPlugin` API, but I don't fully comprehend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this method does is call the Java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` method which runs a program. The method adds a bit of processing on any errors that occur.

The first entry in the string array is the full path of the program to be executed, the rest of the array is arguments to be passed to the program.

So the array

```
new String[] {"/bin/ls", "-l"};
```

would specify that the `/bin/ls` command is to be run with the argument `-l`.